# Adding a standard receptacle to a standard receptacle on a GFCI Circuit

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci

Bathroom 1(Common) has a GFCI receptacle. 
Bathroom 2(Master Bath) has a standard receptacle that is on the same GFCI circuit of Bathroom 1. i.e. If the test button on GFCI in Bathroom 1 is pushed then Bathroom 2's receptacle does not work.

I need to add another receptacle to Bathroom 2 for an outlet near the toilet.  What is the best method to pull power from the Standard receptacle in Bathroom 2 while still maintaining the GFCI protection?  Should this new receptacle also be a standard receptacle/GFCI?  Sorry if this is a novice question, but I tried reading the other questions and did not see a similar situation.

Thanks for your time and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any sockets placed after a GFCI are protected by the GFCI. So a standard socket will suffice.

One of these toys (make sure it has the GFCI test function) is invaluable. Put it into a standard socket to test the wiring - and then press the button. If that socket is protected, the appropriate GFCI will click off.

[image: http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008E07HM2]